# Loading file from resources when using modules

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javafx, java-11

I am trying to load a FXML file from resources directory to show a JavaFX window, however whatever I do I am unable to find the correct way to reference the resource.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
src
    main
        java
            gui
                App.java
            module-info.java
        resources
            MainWindow.fxml
out
    production
        classes
            // All compiled classes
        resources
            MainWindow.fxml
```

The contents of `module-info.java` are following:

```
module MyApp {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    exports gui;
}
```

I'm trying to load the MainWindow.fxml file in App.java like this:
`getClass().getResource("/MainWindow.fxml");`

I've tried using `MainWindow.fxml` and `/MainWindow.fxml` names, however both return null. As can be seen from the directory structure, contents of resources are copied as well, so they should be available at runtime. Resources directory is marked as such in IntelliJ. I'm using Gradle for dependency management.

How can I load files from the resources directory?

Here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.5'
}

group 'MyApp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.11

javafx {
    modules = [
            'javafx.controls',
            'javafx.graphics',
            'javafx.fxml'
    ]
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    implementation 'org.openjfx.javafx-controls:11.0.1'
    implementation 'org.openjfx.javafx-fxml:11.0.1'
    implementation 'org.openjfx.javafx-graphics:11.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Maybe: `App.class.getResource("../resources/MainWindow.fxml");`?

Comment: I've tried "../resources/MainWindow.fxml", "/resources/MainWindow.fxml", "resources/MainWindow.fxml", neither of them return a resource.

Comment: For starters, you should open your project to the fxml module, like `opens gui to javafx.fxml`, as in this [sample](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/IDE/IntelliJ/Modular/Gradle/hellofx/src/main/java/module-info.java#L5). Are you using the JavaFX [gradle plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin)? Can you show your build.gradle file?

Comment: @JoséPereda I've added the build.gradle file. I've also added the opens statement, but I think this may be some other issue, since the file cannot be loaded before any related JavaFX is executed.

Comment: You don't need the  `implementation` part, the plugin does that for you. Also you don't need to add `javafx.graphics`, it is added by controls. As for your issue, do you have an exception? Can you post the stacktrace? Have you tried to run the sample I linked before, does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, the sample works (the one where the controls are added programatically). I get  the "Location is not set." exception, but I've pinpointed that to getResource() returning null

Comment: @tofiffe can you please try to build jar (`$ ./gradlew jar` also it might be necessary to specify the main class: `jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'gui.App'
  }
}`) and access the resource using: `InputStream asStream = App.class.getModule().getResourceAsStream("MainWindow.fxml");`

Comment: If you have an stacktrace in your project(due to the location is not set), add it to the question. Do you say the linked samples with FXML don't work for you?

Comment: @caco3 by building the jar I get `Error: Could not find or load main class gui.App
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application`

Comment: You shouldn't need to build the jar just to make this work... The jar won't have the JavaFX classes in the first place...

Comment: @JoséPereda Oh, yes you're right. Running the main method which tries to access the resource from IntelliJ produces the `NullPointerException` but built jar does not

Comment: Oh... Seems I managed to run it in Idea: adding `apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
  module {
    inheritOutputDirs = true
  }
}` to `build.gradle` worked for me... (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48673769/java-9-module-system-resources-files-location) question)

Comment: @caco3 adding the idea plugin and inheritOutputDirs worked! Can you post this as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: The issue here seems to be that the the resources aren't in out/production/classes, hence they are not in the module. If the classes and resources are packaged in a JAR file then App.class.getResource("/MainWindow.fxml") should work - the leading slash is to locate it via an absolute resource name. The only way to fix the exploded case is to patch the module to add the contents of out/production/resources to the module, i.e. `--patch-module MyApp=out/production/resources`.

Comment: @AlanBateman I’d say, if the classes and resources are packaged in a jar file in this specific way, the application would not even start, as it is not possible to specify a sub-directory within a jar file as class path element.