# getResource() method returns null while loading font file, but why?

Tags: java, javafx, font-awesome

So I am trying to use the library called [PreferencesFX](https://github.com/dlsc-software-consulting-gmbh/PreferencesFX), which uses [FontAwesomeFX](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx/src/master/) which throws the following error.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.jensd.fx.fontawesomefx.commons/de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphsFactory.loadFont(GlyphsFactory.java:64)
    at de.jensd.fx.fontawesomefx.commons/de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphsFactory.<init>(GlyphsFactory.java:38)
    at de.jensd.fx.fontawesomefx.fontawesome/de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.utils.FontAwesomeIconFactory.<init>(FontAwesomeIconFactory.java:28)
    at de.jensd.fx.fontawesomefx.fontawesome/de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.utils.FontAwesomeIconFactory.get(FontAwesomeIconFactory.java:33)
    at com.dlsc.preferencesfx@11.7.0/com.dlsc.preferencesfx.view.UndoRedoBox.<init>(UndoRedoBox.java:17)
    at com.dlsc.preferencesfx@11.7.0/com.dlsc.preferencesfx.PreferencesFx.init(PreferencesFx.java:71)
    at com.dlsc.preferencesfx@11.7.0/com.dlsc.preferencesfx.PreferencesFx.<init>(PreferencesFx.java:64)
    at com.dlsc.preferencesfx@11.7.0/com.dlsc.preferencesfx.PreferencesFx.<init>(PreferencesFx.java:55)
    at com.dlsc.preferencesfx@11.7.0/com.dlsc.preferencesfx.PreferencesFx.of(PreferencesFx.java:102)
    at my.package.tryThis(Clusters.java:38)
    at my.package.Main.main(Main.java:17)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.jensd.fx.fontawesomefx.commons/de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphsFactory.loadFont(GlyphsFactory.java:62)
    ... 21 more
Exception running application my.package.Main
```

I found the cause of the problem to sit at [line 62 of the Glyphs Factory class](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx/src/6cbf97484669c4ab79318a158e1dadf59363c85c/fontawesomefx/fontawesomefx-commons/src/main/java/de/jensd/fx/glyphs/GlyphsFactory.java#lines-62) but I have no idea how to fix it.

The method `GlyphsFactory.class.getResource(pathToIconFont)` returns `null`, instead of returning the font file. I can see that the method is loading the font file via path `/de/jensd/fx/glyphs/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf` (which seem to be correct). I can see that the font is loaded from package `de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome` to package `de.jensd.fx.glyphs` but both packages are in different jars.

[image: IntelliJ Screenshot]

Any ideas why `getResource()` returns `null`? I reported it to the developer but it seems the FontAwesomeFX library is abandoned.

I am running this with newest IntelliJ on a Mac OS X Big Sur.

Comment: classes being in different jars don't matter (assuming you add both jars at runtime ofcourse), because it all gets merged

Comment: You link to the BitBucket page for the code you want to use.  Have you tried cloning, building, and trying out any fixes?  If you figure it out you'll have your own-built jar you can use in your project, and you can create a pull request back to the repository.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino That's true before modules. Now with modules resources can be ["encapsulated"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)), and the above stack trace shows the use of modules.

Comment: @BeUndead: I'd rebuild the project but I have no idea what causes the `NullPointerException`. The path to the font file seems to be correct.

Answer (score 4):

I was successful in patching the library (after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021754/why-does-the-getresource-method-return-null-in-jdk-11)) by changing the following line.

```
Font.loadFont(GlyphsFactory.class.getResource(pathToIconFont).openStream(), 10.0D);
```

To this.

```
Font.loadFont(GlyphsFactory.class.getResourceAsStream(pathToIconFont), 10.0D);
```

Comment: What did you do to patch the library? A monkey patch with `sun.misc.Unsafe`? Or another method?